# Syntax error sqlite table not created

Tags: android, database, sqlite

Here is my code I got this error in logcat.

> 10-05 17:40:09.650: E/Database(1595): Failure 1 (near ",": syntax error) on 0x8b2d440 when preparing 'CREATE TABLE mytable ( _id INTEGER PRIMARY, name text not null, desig text not null, salary text not null, join text not null, dpay text not null )'.

```
package example.servant;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class datahandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public static final String KEY_ID="_id";
        public static final String KEY_NAME="name";
        public static final String KEY_DESIG="desig";
        public static final String KEY_SALARY="salary";
        public static final String KEY_DPAY="dpay";
        public static final String KEY_JOIN="join";

        public static final String DATABASE_NAME="servantrecord.sqlite";
        public static final String TABLE_NAME="mytable";
        public static final String TAG="datahandler";
        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;

        public static final String DATABASE_CREATE=("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " ( " + KEY_ID
                + " INTEGER PRIMARY, " + KEY_NAME + " text not null, "
                + KEY_DESIG + " text not null, " + KEY_SALARY + " text not null, "
                + KEY_JOIN + " text not null, " + KEY_DPAY + " text not null )");


        public datahandler(Context context){

            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

            Log.d("datahandler", "Database created");

        }

            @Override
            public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

                    db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
                    Log.d("datahandler", "table created");

            }

            @Override
            public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
                onCreate(db);

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `PRIMARY` with `PRIMARY KEY`.

Change the column `join` to some other name - `join` is a reserved SQL keyword.

Comment: yeah it works "join" was the main problem,Thank You Thanks ALOT :)